# Mongodb aggreagation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose we have a list of schools like this one:

```
[
{
    "school_name” : "School #1",
    "city” : "Frankfurt",
    "country” : "Germany",
},
{
    "school_name” : "School #2",
    "city” : "Frankfurt",
    "country” : "Germany",
},
{
    "school_name” : "School #3",
    "city” : "Madrid",
    "country” : "Spain",
},
{
    "School_name” : "School #4",
    "city” : "Barcelona",
    "country” : "Spain",
}
```

]

Would it be possible with aggregation framework to get a unique list of cities by country like this one:

```
[
{
 "country" : "Germany" 
 "cities" : [Frankfurt,Berlin, ...]
},
{
 "country" : "Spain",
 "cities" : [Madrid,Barcelona, ...]
}
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want "unique" list, you'll have to use "$addToSet" rather than "$push" as mentioned by Neil.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group": { 
        "_id": "$country",
        "cities": {"$addToSet": "$city" },
    }},
    {"$project": { 
        "_id": 0,
        "country": 1,
        "cities": 1
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group": { 
        "_id": "$country",
        "cities": {"$addToSet": "$city" },
    }},
    {"$project": { 
        "_id": 0,
        "country": 1,
        "cities": 1
    }}
])
```

Read up on the [aggregation pipline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) operators in the documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected. It builds a non-unique list of cities. So if you have 10 schools in Berlin, you'll get "Berlin" 10 times in the output.

Comment: @Vasyl Probably my bad that I missed that detail in your question. Simple edit. See the revision that uses $addToSet instead of $push. Look at the operator reference for the difference.

Comment: Neil,Anand Thank you, guys, it works. But I've just realized that my case is a bit more complex: I need to group by regions too. I'll open a new ticket in a few minutes.